# Get AWS Cognito Token for a REST API so I can test it

Tags: api, rest, amazon-cognito, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test a REST API built with AWS, that uses Cognito for authentication. I can't find a way to get the access token on command line (of course works fine with a browser...) so I can test the API itself.

Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a token from the command line, please see [admin-initiate-auth](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-initiate-auth.html).
Here is an example:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id us-west-2_aaaaaaaaa --client-id 3n4b5urk1ft4fl3mg5e62d9ado --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=jane@example.com,PASSWORD=password
```

Please make sure that the client was created without "App client secret" and "Enable username password auth for admin APIs for authentication" is enabled.